# Magento 2 Uncaught Error: Call to undefined method Namespace\Modulename\Mail\Message\Interceptor::setFromAddress()

Tags: customer, email, magento2.3.1

i am sending an email with attachment from observer(normail mail is going but with attachment it is not working)

Namespace/Modulename/etc/di.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <preference for="Magento\Framework\Mail\Message" type="Namespace\Modulename\Mail\Message"/>
</config>
```

Namespace/Modulename/Mail/Message.php

```
<?php

namespace Namespace\Modulename\Mail;

use Zend\Mime\Mime;
use Zend\Mime\PartFactory;
use Zend\Mail\MessageFactory as MailMessageFactory;
use Zend\Mime\MessageFactory as MimeMessageFactory;
class Message implements \Magento\Framework\Mail\MailMessageInterface
{
    /**
     * @var \Zend\Mime\PartFactory
     */
    protected $partFactory;
    /**
     * @var \Zend\Mime\MessageFactory
     */
    protected $mimeMessageFactory;
    /**
     * @var \Zend\Mail\Message
     */
    private $zendMessage;
    /**
     * @var \Zend\Mime\Part[]
     */
    protected $parts = [];
    /**
     * Message constructor.
     *
     * @param \Zend\Mime\PartFactory $partFactory
     * @param \Zend\Mime\MessageFactory $mimeMessageFactory
     * @param string $charset
     */
    public function __construct(PartFactory $partFactory, MimeMessageFactory $mimeMessageFactory, $charset = 'utf-8')
    {
        $this->partFactory = $partFactory;
        $this->mimeMessageFactory = $mimeMessageFactory;
        $this->zendMessage = MailMessageFactory::getInstance();
        $this->zendMessage->setEncoding($charset);
    }
    /**
     * Add the HTML mime part to the message.
     *
     * @param string $content
     * @return $this
     */
    public function setBodyText($content)
    {
        $textPart = $this->partFactory->create();
        $textPart->setContent($content)
            ->setType(Mime::TYPE_TEXT)
            ->setCharset($this->zendMessage->getEncoding());
        $this->parts[] = $textPart;
        return $this;
    }
    /**
     * Add the text mime part to the message.
     *
     * @param string $content
     * @return $this
     */
    public function setBodyHtml($content)
    {
        $htmlPart = $this->partFactory->create();
        $htmlPart->setContent($content)
            ->setType(Mime::TYPE_HTML)
            ->setCharset($this->zendMessage->getEncoding());
        $this->parts[] = $htmlPart;
        return $this;
    }
    /**
     * Add the attachment mime part to the message.
     *
     * @param string $content
     * @param string $fileName
     * @param string $fileType
     * @return $this
     */
    public function setBodyAttachment($content, $fileName, $fileType)
    {
        $attachmentPart = $this->partFactory->create();
        $attachmentPart->setContent($content)
            ->setType($fileType)
            ->setFileName($fileName)
            ->setDisposition(Mime::DISPOSITION_ATTACHMENT)
            ->setEncoding(Mime::ENCODING_BASE64);
        $this->parts[] = $attachmentPart;
        return $this;
    }
    /**
     * Set parts to Zend message body.
     *
     * @return $this
     */
    public function setPartsToBody()
    {
        $mimeMessage = $this->mimeMessageFactory->create();
        $mimeMessage->setParts($this->parts);
        $this->zendMessage->setBody($mimeMessage);
        return $this;
    }
    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function setBody($body)
    {
        return $this;
    }
    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function setSubject($subject)
    {
        $this->zendMessage->setSubject($subject);
        return $this;
    }
    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function getSubject()
    {
        return $this->zendMessage->getSubject();
    }
    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function getBody()
    {
        return $this->zendMessage->getBody();
    }
    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function setFrom($fromAddress)
    {
        $this->zendMessage->setFrom($fromAddress);
        return $this;
    }
    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function addTo($toAddress)
    {
        $this->zendMessage->addTo($toAddress);
        return $this;
    }
    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function addCc($ccAddress)
    {
        $this->zendMessage->addCc($ccAddress);
        return $this;
    }
    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function addBcc($bccAddress)
    {
        $this->zendMessage->addBcc($bccAddress);
        return $this;
    }
    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function setReplyTo($replyToAddress)
    {
        $this->zendMessage->setReplyTo($replyToAddress);
        return $this;
    }
    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function getRawMessage()
    {
        return $this->zendMessage->toString();
    }
    /**
     * @inheritDoc
     */
    public function setMessageType($type)
    {
        return $this;
    }
}
```

Namespace/Modulename/Mail/Template/TransportBuilder.php

```
<?php

namespace Namespace\Modulename\Mail\Template;



class TransportBuilder extends \Magento\Framework\Mail\Template\TransportBuilder
{
    /**
     * @var \Namespace\Modulename\Mail\Message
     */
    protected $message;
    /**
     * Add an attachment to the message.
     *
     * @param string $content
     * @param string $fileName
     * @param string $fileType
     * @return $this
     */


    public function addAttachment($content, $fileName, $fileType)
    {
        $this->message->setBodyAttachment($content, $fileName, $fileType);
        return $this;
    }
    /**
     * After all parts are set, add them to message body.
     *
     * @return $this
     * @throws \Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException
     */
    protected function prepareMessage()
    {
        parent::prepareMessage();
        $this->message->setPartsToBody();
        return $this;
    }
}
```

Mail code in observer -

```
$transport = 
                $this->_transportBuilder
                ->setTemplateIdentifier('xyz') // Send the ID of Email template which is created in Admin panel
                ->setTemplateOptions(
                    ['area' => \Magento\Framework\App\Area::AREA_FRONTEND, // using frontend area to get the template file
                    'store' => \Magento\Store\Model\Store::DEFAULT_STORE_ID,]
                )
                ->setTemplateVars(['data' => $myObject])
                ->setFrom($sender)
                ->addTo($this->scopeConfig->getValue(self::XML_PATH_EMAIL_RECIPIENT, $storeScope))
                ->addAttachment(self::TEST_FILE_CONTENT, self::TEST_FILE_NAME, self::TEST_FILE_TYPE)
                ->getTransport();
            $transport->sendMessage();
            print_r(__('Everything is fine, email has been sent.'));
            $this->inlineTranslation->resume();
```

Normal mail is working but when add code of attachment then getting above errors ":setFromAddress()"

Answer (score 5):

Please try replacing the following code for Function **addAttachment()** in **Namespace/Modulename/Mail/Template/TransportBuilder.php**.

```
public function addAttachment($content, $fileName, $fileType){
        $attachment = new \Zend\Mime\Part($content);
            $attachment->type = $fileType;
            $attachment->disposition = \Zend_Mime::DISPOSITION_ATTACHMENT;
            $attachment->encoding = \Zend_Mime::ENCODING_BASE64;
            $attachment->filename = $fileName;
        return $attachment;
}
```

It worked for me.

Comment: still getting same error - Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined method Namespace\Modulename\Mail\Message\Interceptor::setFromAddress()

Comment: now getting that error - Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function resolve() on null in /var/www/html/xyz/vendor/magento/framework/Mail/Template/TransportBuilder.php:205

Answer (score 0):

```
public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context $context,
        Filesystem $fileSystem,
        \Magento\MediaStorage\Model\File\UploaderFactory $fileUploaderFactory,
        \Vendor\Attachment\Model\Mail\TransportBuilder $transportBuilder,
        \Magento\Framework\Translate\Inline\StateInterface $inlineTranslation,
        \Magento\Framework\App\Config\ScopeConfigInterface $scopeConfig,
        \Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface $storeManager,
        \Magento\Framework\Escaper $escaper
    ) {
        parent::__construct($context,$transportBuilder,$inlineTranslation, $scopeConfig );
        $this->fileUploaderFactory = $fileUploaderFactory;
        $this->fileSystem          = $fileSystem;
        $this->_transportBuilder = $transportBuilder;
        $this->inlineTranslation = $inlineTranslation;
        $this->scopeConfig = $scopeConfig;
        $this->storeManager = $storeManager;
        $this->_escaper = $escaper;
    }
```

use transportbuilderfactory in constructor below is the code to attched file in email

```
if ($filesData['name']) {
             $uploader = $this->fileUploaderFactory->create(['fileId' => 'attachment']);
             $uploader->setAllowRenameFiles(true);
             $uploader->setFilesDispersion(true);
             $uploader->setAllowCreateFolders(true);
             $uploader->setAllowedExtensions(['pdf','docx','doc','odt', 'rtf']);
             $path = $this->fileSystem->getDirectoryRead(DirectoryList::MEDIA)->getAbsolutePath('contactenq_enquiryform');
             $result = $uploader->save($path);
             $upload_document = 'test-doc'.$uploader->getUploadedFilename();
             $filePath = $result['path'].$result['file'];
             $fileName = $result['name'];

            //print_r($filePath);die();
             $ext = explode('.', $fileName);//echo $ext[1];die();

             $val = $ext[1];
```

create file for attachment path **Vendor\Attachment\Model\Mail**

```
<?php

namespace Vendor\Attachment\Model\Mail;

class TransportBuilder extends \Magento\Framework\Mail\Template\TransportBuilder
{

    public function addAttachments($file, $name)
    {
        if (!empty($file) && file_exists($file)) {
            $this->message
            ->createAttachment(
                file_get_contents($file),
                \Zend_Mime::TYPE_OCTETSTREAM,
                \Zend_Mime::DISPOSITION_ATTACHMENT,
                \Zend_Mime::ENCODING_BASE64,
                basename($name)
            );
        }
        return $this;
    }
}
```

Comment: i am send an email from observer.that will work here ?

Comment: you can use the code with all dependencies and It will work.

Comment: can i send attachment which is in pub folder ?

Comment: $path = $this->fileSystem->getDirectoryRead(DirectoryList::MEDIA)->getAbsolutePath('contactenq_enquiryform');  mention path accordingly and it will work